# Linux Debian ACL, is default mask overriden by something in FTP?

Tags: ftp, unix, access-control-list, vsftpd

I have an Linux Debain 10 server running an web project.
The project (parent) folder is as follows:

ls -la:

```
drwxrwxr--+   7 some_user some_group       4096 Jul 21 11:01 .
```

getfacl:

```
# file: .
# owner: some_user
# group: some_group
user::rwx
user:some_user:rwx
group::rwx
group:www-data:rwx
group:some_group:rwx
mask::rwx
other::r--
default:user::rwx
default:user:some_user:rwx
default:group::rwx
default:group:www-data:rwx
default:group:some_group:rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r--
```

As you can see, inheritance rules are set to not limit any privileges (mask = rwx) and to inherit "some_group" with "rwx" as well. **This works when I make the folder with "mkdir" command** it gives me the privileges reqested, but when I upload them **from my Windows 10 machine using FTP client it doesn't work anymore** and stripping privileges for the uploaded subfolder as follows:

ls -la:

```
drwxr-xr-x+   5 some_user some_group   4096 Jul 21 11:01 uploads
```

getfacl:

```
# file: uploads
# owner: some_user
# group: some_group
user::rwx
user:some_user:rwx               #effective:r-x
group::rwx                      #effective:r-x
group:www-data:rwx              #effective:r-x
group:some_group:rwx                  #effective:r-x
mask::r-x
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:user:some_user:rwx
default:group::rwx
default:group:www-data:rwx
default:group:some_group:rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r--
```

**Thus cutting out the write privillege because "mask" is out of sudden "r-x" instead of "rwx"**.

I'v tried Googling, reading docs, setting "umask 007" with no effect and setting "local_umask=007" in config file FTP "/etc/vsftpd.conf" as I'm using VSFTP.

The only way, how I may solve the problem now is manually setting "chmod -R g+w /folder" every time I upload the folder with FTP. **Can I make FTP uploaded files to get assigned with the right privilleges somehow? Any ideas will be appreciate.**

this is close but don't think it has something to do with my problem: [File ACL mask calculation: why?](https://serverfault.com/questions/223733/file-acl-mask-calculation-why)

Comment: Sounds to me like a vsftpd config issue. Check specifically the `vsftpd.conf` file, both global and user, for the settings `local_umask` (I see you've done that one for global, but check the user file if there is one) and `file_open_mode`.

Comment: @tsc_chazz Unfortunelly "file_open_mode=0777" has no effect in global config and my ftp user doesn't have any local configuration. Thanks anyway, guess if I made reproduction it would be simpler to find out the problem, but there's too many "variables" in system I believe.